# Jquery background image css change not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the background image of an element through jquery like this;

```
$j(this).css('background-image','url(images/client_box_grad.gif)');
```

However when it renders it seems to drop speech marks around the the url, eg

```
$j(this).css('background-image','url("images/client_box_grad.gif")');
```

And this means the image isn't visible - if I remove the speech marks in Firebug then the image shows up.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The double quotes are not necessary:

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/client_box_grad.gif)');
```

You should make sure that you have specified a valid image url. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8E45b/).

Comment: Cheers Darin - it works when I stick the absolute path on, I'd like to use relative pathing if possible, as it's sat in a wordpress install where everything has been made relative so nothing broke when I stuck it live from my dev area. I can live with that if I can't use any form  of relative pathing though. Also it seems to add in the double quotes as part of the replacement - they are not there in any of the code.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I had to do to get it to work:

```
$(function(){
$('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(/media/bill.jpg)'});
});
```

Comment: I have tried all other ways that are mentioned in other answers. No one worked form me. But your solution is worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
$(this).css('background-image','url(images/client_box_grad.gif)');

// OR
$(this).css('background', 'url("images/client_box_grad.gif")');
```