# Multiple image change throughout document on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, multiple-instances

I have a website I'm building that uses background images to display the pictures i want in the divs via CSS

I want to create a single image, that when pressed "ON", toggles different background images for different classes. I would also like this to remain through out the site, so if you change page, it doesn't revert to it's "OFF" state.

is there a j query or java-script that could easily achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

related :

- [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)
- [Changing background image using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578714/changing-background-image-using-jquery)
- [jquery change background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832140/jquery-change-background-image)
- [Jquery background image css change not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874430/jquery-background-image-css-change-not-working)

  ```
  $(function() {
  $("img")
      .clic(function() { 
          $('.your-element1).css({'background-image':'url(images/your-new-image.jpg)'});
  });
  ```

Comment: how can i make this fade over 2/3 seconds? sorry for not including that originally

Comment: Hmmmm, that sounds like another question to me ;)